# How to retrieve and print (or echo) data from database?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, textfield

I managed to achieve specific database array order, now I'd like to print it in proper combination, but I have no idea how the 'foreach' loop should look like.

What I have now is:

```
$textfields = get_settings('test_testbutton');
if (!empty($textfields)) {
    foreach ($textfields as $textfield) {
        ?>
        <p>
            <input type="text" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" name="test_testbutton[0][]" value="<?php echo $textfield; ?>" placeholder="Input Value"/>
            <input type="text" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" name="test_testbutton[1][]" value="<?php echo $textfield; ?>" placeholder="Input Value"/>
            <a href="#" id="removebutton">Remove</a>
        </p>
    <?php
    }
} else {
}
```

I really don't know how to change 'echo $textfield' and make it work. I tried adding [] to '$textfields' value and then echo $textfield[] or $textfield[0], but with no success :(

I attached a .jpg file to make it more understandable.

[attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pzGO.jpg)

Comment: What is in `$textfields`? Do `var_dump($textfields)` and show us the result.

Comment: In general: Try to output `$textfield` with `<pre><?php var_dump($textfield) ?></pre>`, You should get an idea, what is in `$textfield`. (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) @Styphon Wow, 15 seconds earlier ;-)

Comment: `<?php echo $value['id']; ?>` Where is $value ?

Comment: What does the jpeg show? What is the JSON Code above the Input fields and where does it come from? What is it you want to display in textfield? Do you know your Database structure (or do you just query blindly and never checked what the tables look like?)

Comment: Guys!!, var_dump($textfiels) shows array(2) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "1234" [1]=> string(4) "qwer" [2]=> string(4) "abcd" } [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "5678" [1]=> string(4) "tyui" [2]=> string(4) "efgh" } } , so it's basically exactly the same what's in .jpg image I used as an attachment. I know what I have in $textfield, I only need a help to retreive it. Did you even see the jpg file? @Debflav You don't need $value['id'], it's irrelevant for my question! Why two negative grades for this question???

Comment: It was not irrelevant. Thought it was an error or a missing value. Anyway, it is better to update your question with the debug please. It seems that you must use two foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your update. It seems that you forget a foreach. I hope it's helpful to achieve what you want.

```
    // Following your dump
    $textfields = array( 0 => array( 1234, "qwer", "abcd"), 1 => array("5678", "tyui", "efgh"));

    if (!empty($textfields)) {
        foreach ($textfields as $textfield) {
            // First loop : 0 => array( 1234, "qwer", "abcd")
            // Second loop: 1 => array("5678", "tyui", "efgh")
            foreach ($textfield as $oneValue) {
                // Loop on the second array $textfield
            }
    }
```

Comment: Now I echoed both loops and it gave me: Array1234qwerabcdArray5678tyuiefgh. I'n not sure how to group displayed result by two corresponding values, i.e.: 1234 next to 5678, qwer next to tyui, etc.

Comment: I wrapped every loop with a div `if (!empty($textfields)) {
        foreach ($textfields as $textfield) {
   ?><div><?php 
   foreach ($textfield as $oneValue) {
                 echo "<p>".$oneValue."</p>";
           } ?></div><?php
    }}` so i works perfect now!! Thaks a lot:)

Answer (score 0):

The Text in the attached image is a serialized array, so if you want to use `foreach` on this text you have to `unserialize` it, then an array will be created

```
$arr = unserialize($textfields);
```

Comment: When I use '$textfields = get_settings('test_testbutton');' the array is already created, so I can't use 'unserialize'. Anyway Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you and it will work :)

```
$textfields_data = get_settings('test_testbutton');
if (!empty($textfields_data)) 
{
    $textfields = unserialize($textfields_data);
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($textfields as $textfield) {
        ?>
        <p>
            <input type="text" id="" name="test_testbutton1_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $textfield[$i]; ?>" placeholder="Input Value"/>
            <input type="text" id="" name="test_testbutton2_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $textfield[$i]; ?>" placeholder="Input Value"/>
            <a href="#" id="removebutton">Remove</a>
        </p>
    <?php
    $i++;
    }
} 
else 
{
}
```

Comment: I tried but it returns: 'unserialize() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in...' and 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in...'